# React JS: Passing function as props is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, snackbar, alerts

I'm fairly new to React JS and I have a question. I've been trying to search the internet about my problem but I cannot find a solution. Here it goes: I have 2 files, Header.tsx and Alerts.tsx. In Header.tsx there is a function named alertData that indicates the severity of an alert.

```
const Header = () => {

   useEffect(() => {
   setSomething(getSomething(alertData));
   }, []);

   const alertData = (data: any) => {
   const type: SOMETHING_TYPE = data.type
   switch (type) {
     case 'HEALTH': {
       const message = {
          type: 'info',
          message: `Healthy:`
       }
       return message;
     }
     case 'WARNING': {
    const alert: Alert = data;
      const message = {
          type: 'error',
          message: `Warning: ${alert.severity}`
       }
       return message;
     }
   }

   return (
     <header>
        <Alerts data = {alertData}>
     </header>
   )

}
```

Here is the Alerts.tsx:

```
const Alerts = (data) => {

console.log("Data:", data)
const classes = useStyles();
const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);


const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
  if (reason === 'clickaway') {
    return;
  }

setOpen(false);
};

return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose} anchorOrigin={{ 
        vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}>
      <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity={type}>
         { message }
      </Alert>
  </Snackbar>
</div>
);
}
```

I have put `alertData` as a props for `<Alert/>` in Header.tsx but alert is still not showing in the UI. I've checked in console.log and this is the data that is being passed:
[image]

I was expecting message to be passed to Alerts so that it can be displayed in the UI but its not showing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you passed a function instead of a message variable, is because in your Header.tsx you did not evaluate the `alertData` function.

```
const Header = () => {
  // ...

  return (
    <header>
      <Alerts data={alertData}>
    </header>
  );
}
```

it should be changed to:

```
const Header = () => {
  const [someData, setSomeData] = useState();

  return (
    <header>
      <Alerts data={alertData(someData)}>
    </header>
  );
}
```

And yet, in your Alerts.tsx, the variable `data` is actually an object that wrapping the field `data` instead of the data you want. therefore, you should rewrite the component `Alerts` from:

```
const Alerts = (data) => {
}
```

To

```
// first approach: es6 destructing assignment
const Alerts = ({data}) => {
  // ...
}

// second approach: create a new variable
const Alerts = (props) => {
  const data = props.data;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Another question, where do I set setSomeData?

Comment: By calling a function, you need argument to call it, in the answer, `someData` means the argument, nothing else, for the better standing so I wrote it a state instead. Therefore, you just need to do is substituting `someData` with other value that make sense in the context of your program then that will do.